# Django dictsort not working with date

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a simple pair of models for working with time series:

```
class Ticker(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

     def latest_datapoint(self):
         return self.datapoint_set.order_by('-timestamp')[0]

     def latest_value(self):
         return self.latest_data_point().value

     def latest_timestamp(self)
         return self.latest_data_point().timestamp

class DataPoint(models.Model):
     ticker = ForeignKeyField(Ticker)
     timestamp = DateTimeField()
     value = FloatField()
```

I then use a generic class based view to make a ticker list:

```
class TickerListView(ListView):
    model = Ticker
    template_name = 'ticker-list.html'
```

Lastly, I implement the template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Latest Value</th>
            <th>Latest Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for object in object_list %}  <----***Let's talk about this***
            <tr>
                <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ object.latest_value}}</td>
                <td>{{ object.latest_timestamp}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor % }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As written, this works just fine.  But I would like to order my results **in the template** using dictsort.  If I replace the highlighted line with `{% for object in object_list|dictsort:"latest_value" %}` everything works fine.  But if I instead write`{% for object in object_list|dictsort:"latest_timestamp" %}` everything comes in blank , as if I had specified an invalid key to sort on.  Any idea what's going on here?

(Hypothesis: dictsort doesn't know how to handle `datetime.datetime` data types when ordering.)

Thanks.

### Added in response to Hieu Nguyen:

Thanks for your comment!  So of course I'm getting burned because I have oversimplified the example above.  In my actual code the method definitions for `Ticker` look like:

```
     def latest_datapoint(self):
         if self.datapoint_set:
             return self.datapoint_set.order_by('-timestamp')[0]
         else:
             return None

     def latest_value(self):
         if self.latest_datapoint():
             return self.latest_data_point().value
         else:
             return None

     def latest_timestamp(self)
         if self.latest_datapoint():             
             return self.latest_data_point().timestamp
         else:
             return None
```

When I try to dictsort on `latest_value` everything works fine, even if several of the Tickers have `latest_value() = None`.  But when I dictsort on `latest_timestamp` when some of those are `None` then Django seems to skip the table entirely.  Is the lesson here that `None` can be cleanly compared with Float data but not with DateTime data?  If so, Would a `latest_timestamp_text` method, which coerces all timestamps into a `YYYYMMDD HHMMSS` format (with `None` being converted to `0`) suffice as a key on which to perform in-template dictsorts?

### Edited again:

This still doesn't seem to sort it out.  I have implemented a new method:

```
def latest_timestamp_safe(self):
    if self.latest_timestamp() is None:
        return datetime.now().replace(year=1975)
    else:
        return self.latest_timestamp()
```

I have confirmed that this is working and that all the rows in my table display a nice tz-aware datetime in the column I made for latest_timestamp_safe.  However I still cannot dictsort on this key.  Any thoughts?

### Edit last time:

Above doesn't work.  As Hieu points out this doesn't suffice to make the "safe" datetime tz aware.  So I just gave up on that and went with the stringifying idea.  Works fine.  Compares with `None` in the expected way.

Comment: This works fine with my test so for sure `datetime` is not a problem, are you sure that `latest_timestamp` is displayed fine for the whole list?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question! I had oversimplified my example above.  I have given a more thorough and accurate description in my edit.  Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is true. It seems that `dictsort` can't handle to compare `None` value with `datetime` object anyhow. Even if you return a very small datetime object like:

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

the list will be blank too.

So the solution would be converting datetime object to text and use it, also return `''` instead of `None` so it doesn't take time to convert `None` to something else when sorting:

```
def latest_timestamp_text(self)
    if self.latest_datapoint():             
        return self.latest_data_point().timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        return ''
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I didn't know that Django's `DateTimeField` will produce datetime object with timezone info. So of course it cannot be compared to a normal datetime object without that info:

```
>>> dt1 = datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 21, 16, 30, tzinfo=gmt2)
>>> dt2 = datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 22, 16, 30)
>>> dt1 > dt2
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

So if you still want to use the datetime object without converting to text, you have to make a timezone info class, something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

class GMT2(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=2) + self.dst(dt)

    def dst(self, dt):
        d = datetime(dt.year, 4, 1)
        self.dston = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
        d = datetime(dt.year, 11, 1)
        self.dstoff = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
        if self.dston <= dt.replace(tzinfo=None) < self.dstoff:
            return timedelta(hours=1)
        else:
            return timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "GMT +2"
```

Then change your function like this:

```
def latest_timestamp(self):
    gmt2 = GMT2()
    if self.latest_datapoint():             
        return self.latest_data_point().timestamp
    else:
        return datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 1, tzinfo=gmt2)
```

Note: 1970 is the minimum value for year.

I would prefer converting to text over this method but well it's your choice.

Comment: I'm shocked that the `datetime.datetime(1900,1,1,1,1)` still doesn't work.  Any idea why that would be the case?  Could that be a timezone issue?  The DateTimeField values will all have some timezone data on them, but by default would your 1900?

Comment: Nope `datetime.now()` doesn't create tz-aware datetime object. If you want to create such object, use the same way I show aboved with `GMT2` class, so `gmt2 = GMT2()` then `return datetime.now(gmt2).replace(year=1975)`. You can't just go around that problem ;)

Comment: Hah. Ok. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Really fantastic answers, Hieu.  I went with stringifying the dates and it worked fine.  None and strings compare in the expected way.